# PHP Responsive Conditional Includes

Tags: php, css, mobile

I'm having a problem with a Responsive Layout.

The layout has to include the same php file on different places depending on browser width.

**display:none;** still loads the content and possibly breaks code within said file.

```
<div id="more_than_960">
    <?php require "content.php";?>
</div>

<div id="less_than_960">
    <?php require "content.php";?>
</div>
```

Is there a better way in achieving the goal?

The problem isn't to hide the content, but to exclude it from the loading process.

---

**To anyone else having this problem. Here's a great solution provided my Markus:**

https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

Comment: So you would want to *refresh* the page any time the window was altered above or below 960?

Comment: I don't want to refresh the page automatically when browser is being re-sized. The goal is to only include a certain file via php when viewing the website from a smaller screen. eg. Tablets, Phones etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't do responsive on the server side, you should do it on the client side, using `@media` queries and where necessary javascript. So you would have something like:

```
@media (min-width:960px) {
    .somestuff {
        display: none;
}
```

etc.

So you need to change your approach a bit. Make content which degrades well instead of inserting duplicated content.

If you really need to do part of this on the server side, you probably don't want to ask for width but directly detect a certain group of devices with a library like this https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect.

Furthermore, you probably want to separate your markup from your content.

```
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    $markup = 'your markup';
}
else if ($detect->isTablet()) {
    $markup = 'your alternative markup';
}
```

Comment: I have done this as far as possible.
I have no control over the design. The layouts are too drastically different to achieve this without duplicating the content via php includes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at the Mobile-Detect option.
I think this might be the way to solve my problem.

Comment: I couldn't connect to stackoverflow for the past hour. But this Mobile Detect script works perfectly. It was just the thing I was looking for. Thanks a lot kind sir.

Answer (score 3):

Use media query for display content. No need to show/hide div

See this link for help http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-web-design-with-media-queries

Comment: If the content is completely different and doesn't just have different CSS, show/hide or even different markup will be necessary. But the link you posted is great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `If-Else function` and use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to check what device is being used. and make one div being loaded.

Comment: Hi, I managed to fix my problem with another solution. Thanks in any case.